# iOS/Javascript - How to access images on device using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, xcode

I'm working on a native ios app and am trying to set up the javascript to add bundle resources into a web page.

Is it possible to use local bundle resources and display them in the web view?

The page is all set up, I know where I want the image. I just need a way to tell the html to reference the image on the device. So when the page loads i can set (img src = "/SomeDirectoryOnIphone/myImage.png").

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`/private/var/mobile/media/DCIM/100APPLE/` stores the images, but they are numbered. The images are named `IMG_324.JPG` or whatever number. I don't think you can call it `myImage.png`.